# Windows XP, Preference menu's hidden for many programs

Tags: windows-xp, netbeans, adobe-illustrator

I don't know when this started happening, but it has been several months since I first noticed it.

Basically, when I go to a preferences menu of some programs, the preferences window is completely hidden, but the program see's it as being open. This prevents me from interacting with the preferences and the actual program. So far I've noticed it on Adobe Illustrator and Netbeans. Illustrator when I select edit - > Preferences -> An Option. On Netbeans it happens when I right click on a site and select properties.

Here's a screenshot from when I click on the preferences menu. Note that the main workspace is grayed out. I have to hit Escape to close the hidden preferences window:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried unstinstalling, completely wiping the registry of any trace of the program and reinstalling. Thought it may have been a multi-monitor issue when I switched from 2 monitors down to 1, but menu's were not on other monitor when I plugged one back in. I've reset workspaces, windows display, windows performance settings, changed resolution, safe mode, everything I can think of. I cannot figure out what would cause the same problem on completely unrelated software, and I cannot reset it by reinstalling. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window may be coming up off the edge of the screen.

When the hidden window is active, press Alt+Space, select Move, then press an arrow key on the keyboard to attach the window to the mouse pointer. Then you can move the mouse (or press the arrow keys) to move the window where you want it, then click the mouse button (or press Enter) to drop the window.

Comment: That did it. Such a simple fix, so frusterating.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms are similar to what happens when a system runs out of GDI resources; but a reboot would fix that.

Can other applications show dialogs? Internet Explorer's options? Windows Explorer folder options?

Edit: i misunderstood what i was seeing. i thought you said that the large gray rectangle was the preferences dialog, but it was empty. i see now that the large gray rectangle is the document on the main screen.  So i'll go with the other other: the dialog is off the screen.

Try pressing:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up the system menu
- Press <kbd>M</kbd>, to select Move
- Press <kbd>Down</kbd> to lock the window to the cursor
- move the cursor around, onto the main screen

Comment: Yes, most programs work as normal. Explorer, IE, Firefox, just about everything else is unaffected. Also, some popup dialogs are fine. In Illustrator, I can interact with "Document Setup" and others, just not preferences. Adobe Photoshop and Indesign work completely fine as well.